# Can I remove my oven's wire conduit to save space?

Tags: wiring

I am wiring our new stove top & oven. They both came with probably four feet of wire that is enclosed in this heavy metal flexible conduit. I don't have room behind my oven for all of this metal  conduit. How can I remove a part of this metal conduit on the wiring on my new stove top & oven?

Comment: To clarify, is the metal conduit attached to the new appliances, or to your house?  A picture of both the appliances and where you intend to connect would be helpful -- you can edit your post to add them in.

Comment: Can you post photos of the space you're trying to install the cooktop and oven into please?

Comment: Does the appliance have any special instructions about where the electrical connection to the wall must be made?

Answer (score 3):

You have that much so that you can make the connection, then put the appliance in place. There's generally no problem with finding space for it, as it naturally ends up behind and/or underneath the appliance as you push the appliance in.

Rushing to shorten it may make it impossible, or **very, very difficult** to connect the appliance to power. Correcting THAT may require ordering replacement, uncut, feed wires. Proceed cautiously and deliberately.

If it's typical spiral flex, you cut across the spiral strip (so not straight across the cable as a whole) and usually have to bend the cable a bit to get the spiral to snap, then you need to insert a bushing to keep the cut metal from damaging the wires.

Answer (score 1):

I would presume that the "conduit" is a flexible metal spiral, not a hard tube (which, frankly, was my first thought when I read "conduit").

When you consider the depth of the plug at the end of the wire, it's probably not much thinner than the conduit, and the plug is probably attached at a 90° angle so that when you plug it into the wall, the plug itself will stick out *almost* as far as the cable does and will direct the cable against the wall, not away from the wall.

Once it's plugged in, carefully push the stove back against the wall, ensuring that the conduit doesn't cross over itself, and it will take up as much room as the plug itself does.

If, when you've pushed the stove back as far against the wall as you can<sup>*</sup>, (carefully sandwiching the plug and conduit between them), the stove is still sticking out from the rest of the cabinets, your options are (in order of increasing expense and difficulty):

1. Live with it
2. Return the stove and get one that is shallower
3. Get deeper cabinets installed to match the depth of the stove

<sup>*</sup>Make sure you check the installation instructions for the stove - there may be a requirement that you leave a gap between the back of the stove and the plug itself.